# TSQL - Searching for a name that can have 1, 2 or 3 parts

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to create a query that will return a persons name from a table.

The table contains a field called full_name.

I have created a full text index on the table on that field.

I have the following query

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetContactFromContactName]
@contactname VARCHAR(200) 
AS
DECLARE @searchstr VARCHAR(200)
set @searchstr = '"'+REPLACE(@contactname,',','*" OR ''')+'*"'
select * from tbl_ContactDetails
where contains(Full_Name,@searchstr)
```

This works, but only in certain circumstances.

If the field contains the name **John James Jones** the query works if you enter any of the following:

- John
- James
- Jones
- John James
- James Jones
- John James Jones

but it doesn't work if you enter **John Jones**.

I have searched online for a solution, which is where the above query came from. Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Your original procedure doesn't treat space correctly.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetContactFromContactName]
   @contactname VARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @searchstr VARCHAR(200)
   SET @contactname = REPLACE(REPLACE(@contactname, ',', '|'), ' ', '|')
   SET @searchstr = '"' + REPLACE(@contactname, '|', '*" OR "') + '*"'
   SELECT   *
   FROM     tbl_ContactDetails
   WHERE    CONTAINS ( Full_Name, @searchstr )
END
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response stonetiger. It works very well, in fact to well. Is there anyway of restricting the number of rows to what the user has actually entered? Thanks again

Comment: Have answered my own question, need to replace the OR with AND.